# How to pass object field as directive argument in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass object array to directive and have it print out the fields which I determine at the place where I use that directive.

Here's the example:

```
//directive
app.directive('MyDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
    scope: {
      items: '@',
      field: '@'
    }
  };
});

// my-directive.html template
<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.field }}</div>
```

The idea is that I could use it with any object like this:

```
// object arrays
var phones = [{id:1,number:'555-5555'}, {id:2,number:'555-6666'}];
var persons = [{id:1,name:'John'}, {id:2,name:'Jane'}];


// directive usage
<div my-directive items="phones" data-field="???number???"></div>
<div my-directive items="persons" data-field="???name???"></div>
```

The result should print out numbers and names. Is that even doable in Javascript?

Comment: If you want bind to varaible from scope use = instead of @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, just bind the items with '=':

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item[field] }}</div>',
    scope: {
      items: '=',
      field: '@'
    }
  };
})
```

Then use it like this:

```
<div my-directive items="phones" field="number"></div>
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/slsWJuRDjKAgVO8BEiTa?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, you can do it like this:

**Directive:**

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{ getItemField(item) }}</div>',
        scope: {
          items: '=',
          field: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.getItemField = function (item) {
                return item[scope.field];
            };
        }

      };
```

**HTML:**

```
<div my-directive items="phones" data-field="number"></div>
<div my-directive items="persons" data-field="name"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12453/)

Comment: Thanks! Your version is working but the function part apparently isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't take a directive, probably the directive you are looking for is ng-repeat:

```
var phones = [{id:1,number:'555-5555'}, {id:2,number:'555-6666'}];
var persons = [{id:1,name:'John'}, {id:2,name:'Jane'}];

<li ng-repeat="phone in phones">{{phone.number}}</li>

<li ng-repeat="person in persons">{{person.name}}</li>
```

Comment: The actual directive does much more but I left it from here to make it clearer.